# Cannot find module X imported from Y - Playwright with Typescript

Tags: typescript, playwright, sveltekit

I just installed a new version of SvelteKit with Playwright and TS. I am trying to import a regular `.ts` file inside my `A.spec.ts` file.

```
tests
  A.spec.ts
  B.ts
```

**a.spec.ts**

```js
import { test, expect } from "@playwright/test";
import { mymodule } from './B';
...
```

I get the following error when I run `npm run test` (playwright test):

```
Error: Cannot find module 'my\imported-module\path\tests\B' imported from A.spec.ts
```

VS Code does not show any errors with my code.

How can I import a regular TS file into my playwright TS testing script?

J

**UPDATE** -  Here is a basic [Github Repo](https://github.com/jdgamble555/testing-import)

Comment: If as an experiment you move `utils.ts` one directory up and import it as `import { my_module } from '../utils.ts';`, do you still get an error? I haven't used Playright yet myself, but maybe all the files in the `tests` directory has to be test files.

Comment: Nope, I get the same error. 

Comment: 1 year later and still cannot figure out how to import typescript modules into the tests :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

`import { my_module } from './utils';`

To:

`import { my_module } from './utils.js';`

This an issue with ESM in node and happens when using `"type": "module"`.

> imports will fail in ES modules because relative import paths need to use extensions.
> As a result, it will have to be rewritten to use the extension of the output of foo.ts, so instead we have to import from ./foo.js.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/esm-node.html

Comment: Thanks, yeah, playwright claims it is not a bug, but obviously this is not natural - https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/19710

Comment: Ah, it's a Node / ESM  issue, not a bug in Playwright.